# How to add border radius to angular mat table?

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-table

I am trying to make the `mat-table` border as round. But it is not working. Tried this-

```
table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-radius: 1em;
}
```

How to achieve this?

Comment: Where did you write this code?

Comment: would be good if you provided also html that you use

Answer (score 9, accepted):

the problem is that you need over-ride the background-color of mat-table:

```
.mat-table
{
  background-color:transparent!important;  
}
table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-radius: 5em;
}
table tr:last-child td /*To remove the last border*/
{
  border-bottom:0 solid
}
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cjxcgt-ese4v3?file=app%2Ftable-basic-example.css)

Comment: Thanks, @Eliseo for the right direction. Doesn't know why I got downvote for the question and got wrong answers from others! :/

Comment: This doesn't work. If you add `border: 1px solid black;` it does not make the edges rounded. This solution doesn't have a visible border.

Comment: use `border-collapse:separate;` instead of `border-collapse: collapse;`

Answer (score 13):

The most simple solution that worked for me was to hide the overflow of certain elements that gave the unfinished look when we set the border-radius. So, we just handle that

```
.mat-table{    
    border-radius: 8px;
    overflow:hidden !important;
}
```

Feel free to point out cases where this might cause other issues.

Comment: It works, however if there's a border width, it doesn't show.

Comment: Works, but when you use stick header, this does not work. Because overflow:hidden effects the whole thing.

Answer (score 1):

Update:

@Eliseo answer works if you add border to `mat-table`: border: solid 1px grey;

```
    .mat-table
    {
      background-color:transparent!important;  
      border: solid 1px grey;
    }
    table {
      width: 100%;
      border-collapse: collapse;
      border-radius: 5em;
    }
    table tr:last-child td /*To remove the last border*/
    {
      border-bottom:0 solid
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This CSS code working in Mat table border Radius

CSS code for Mat table border radius
[image]

```
th.mat-header-cell:first-of-type, td.mat-cell:first-of-type, td.mat-footer-cell:first-of-type {
  padding-left: 24px;
  border-top-left-radius: 9px;
}
th.mat-header-cell:last-of-type, td.mat-cell:last-of-type, td.mat-footer-cell:last-of-type {
  padding-right: 24px;
  border-top-right-radius: 9px;
}
```

Comment: for apply the same style of your picture is sufficen use

th.mat-header-cell:first-of-type { border-top-left-radius: 9px; }

 and 

th.mat-header-cell:last-of-type{ border-top-right-radius: 9px; }

Answer (score -1):

If you want it in whole application just add it in you main css with **!important** like following

```
.mat-table {
  width: 100% !important;
  border-collapse: collapse !important;
  border-radius: 1em !important;
}
```

or if this doesnt works there is another way 
to use `/deep/` Or ::deep

although it is not best practice and is also deprecated but solves the purpose

Comment: I think it is a better practice to create a class for the mat-table in style.css (it will be available for the whole application), and second, if the CSS selectors were well formed there's no need for !important or ::deep. Those are kinda hacky.

Answer (score -1):

Your styling problems don't have to do with Angular Material tables but with HTML tables in general. If you search for how to style a table e.g. add borders to rows or margins you'll find various answers and suggestions.

**You basically can't add margin or padding to a table row  directly.**

> `margin` applies to all elements except elements with table display types other than table-caption, table and inline-table.
>
> `padding` applies to all elements except table-row-group, table-header-group, table-footer-group, table-row, table-column-group and table-column.

***Solutions***

How you set a `border` for table rows and specify a `margin` and `padding` depends on the border model (`collapse` or `separate`) you use.

**The separated borders model: border-collapse: seperate**

> In the **separated borders model**, the edges coincide with the border edges of cells. (And thus, in this model, there may be gaps between the rows, columns, row groups or column groups, corresponding to the 'border-spacing' property.)
>
> In this model, each cell has an individual border. The 'border-spacing' property specifies the distance between the borders of adjoining cells. (...) Rows, columns, row groups, and column groups cannot have borders (i.e., user agents must ignore the border properties for those elements).

1. **Solution**: If you want a **border, margin and padding** you could do something like this:

   td.mat-cell {
   /* row padding */
   padding: 16px 0;
   /* row border */
   border-bottom: 1px solid #ffa600;
   border-top: 1px solid #ffa600;
   }

   td.mat-cell:first-child {
   /* row border */
   border-left: 1px solid #ffa600;
   }

   td.mat-cell:last-child {
   /* row border */
   border-right: 1px solid #ffa600;
   }

   table {
   /* row spacing / margin */
   border-spacing: 0 8px !important;
   }

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cjxcgt-wtkfg4

The collapsing border model: border-collapse: collapse
The edges of the rows, columns, row groups and column groups in the collapsing borders model coincide with the hypothetical grid lines on which the borders of the cells are centered. (And thus, in this model, the rows together exactly cover the table, leaving no gaps; ditto for the columns.)

In the collapsing border model, it is possible to specify borders that surround all or part of a cell, row, row group, column, and column group. (...) Also, in this model, a table does not have padding (but does have margins).

2. **Solution**: If you only want a row border and padding but no spacing / margin between the rows you could do:

   table {
   border-collapse: collapse;
   }

   th {
   /* row border */
   border-bottom: 1px solid #ffa600;
   }

   td.mat-cell {
   /* row padding */
   padding: 20px 0;
   border: none;
   }

   tr.mat-row {
   /* row border */
   border: 1px solid #ffa600;
   }

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cjxcgt-xphbue

Answer (score -1):

```css
simply add this to your css file: 

table, th, td { border-radius: 10px; }
```

simply add this to your css file:

table, th, td { border-radius: 10px; }

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33500492)

Answer (score -1):

```css
thead,
tr,
th {
    border-radius: 8px;
}
tbody {
    tr:last-child {
        td {
            border-radius: 8px;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34475297)